# Adding secondary constructor to parent unexpectedly affects child classes

Tags: constructor, kotlin

I have a (seemingly) odd problem. It can be reproduced with just a few lines:

```
open class Parent(val map: HashMap<String, Any>) {
    // constructor(unusedArgument: Int): this(hashMapOf())
}

class Child: Parent(hashMapOf(Pair("key", "value")))
```

It compiles and works as expected as long as I keep `Parent`'s secondary constructor commented out.
Once I put it back in, this lint error pops up where the `Child`'s parent constuctor is called:

> Error: None of the following functions can be called with the
>   arguments supplied:
>
> public constructor Parent(map: HashMap) defined in Parent
>
> public constructor Parent(unusedArgument: Int) defined in Parent

The error goes away if any of these is true:

- I specify variance as `HashMap<String, out Any>`,
- My secondary constructor is empty,
- `map` is declared as `Map` instead of `HashMap` (which I don't do because for my purposes I need it to implement `Serializable`).

To be honest, it doesn't make much sense to me. Why does it happen only if I add non-empty secondary constructor to the parent class? What does it have to do with anything? And how exactly do these "fixes" fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be by design or a compiler bug. I recommend reporting it at [Kotlin (KT) | YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).

As a workaround, you can explicitly declare the generic types used in the `HashMap` when calling the `Parent` constructor:

```
class Child : Parent(hashMapOf<String, Any>(Pair("key", "value")))
```

I'm not certain why  the compiler accepts `HashMap<String, String>` as `HashMap<String, Any>` when the secondary constructor isn't defined but doesn't accept it when the secondary constructor is defined but sometimes the compiler simply fails to infer generic types and you need to explicitly declare them.

Comment: I assumed I was missing something but yes, it certainly looks like a bug. Thanks, I guess I'll report it then.